# How to get gcp project name by project id

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Using cloud function - trying to make get call to get the project name and with the id - https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#listing_projects

```
 from googleapiclient import discovery
 from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials as creds
 crm = discovery.build(
     'cloudresourcemanager', 'v3', 
      http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

 project = crm.projects().get(name="projects/"+projectId).execute()
```

`

Comment: The link you put in your question has example Python code. What is the problem?

Comment: @JohnHanley - If I have a project id - prj-mmm-test-11234 and how can I get the name for the id. That's what I am looking for, the code is just giving me the get project.

Comment: Again what is the problem? You are using the correct code to get the project details. The member `name` is the Project Name.

Comment: @JohnHanley - what is projectId. Because I want to give the value for project id and i want to get the name for that project id. Not all the project name, only the given project id

Comment: @user3713336 your code is correct, if you have your project_id in projectId variable, this code will execute (given the auth goes through) and will store the [Project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects#Project) instance into the project variable. If this doesn't work for you, tell us what exactly doesn't work, what the error is or any details that you think could help

Comment: I figured it out = project_name = project['displayName']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials as creds
crm = discovery.build(
 'cloudresourcemanager', 'v3', 
  http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

project = crm.projects().get(name="projects/"+projectId).execute()
project_name = project['displayName']
```